# Ansible Inventory: How to use localhost in a host group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We are using Ansible as a way to setup and manage a k8s cluster.
To deploy application we have a playbook that uses `localhost` to call `kubectl` to deploy our application.

We are doing some refactoring and I would like a make `localhost` a part of a group in Ansible host file.

Currently we have:

```ini
localhost ansible_connection=local ansible_user=root

[k8s_masters]
k8s-master01 ansible_host=x

[k8s_nodes]
k8s-node01 ansible_host=x
k8s-node02 ansible_host=x

[k8s_cluster:children]
k8s_masters
k8s_nodes
```

I would like to add the host `localhost` to the group `k8s_cluster`.

So that when I run my playbook Ansible wil use `k8s_cluster` group_var when executing on `localhost`. I know that I can use the `group_var/all` but our setup is somewhat complicated. And we want to use this setup to match the right variables depending on the inventory that is used.

Is this at all possible to create a group of multiple hosts that also includes `localhost`?

I tried to create a group `prod`:

```ini
[prod:children]
all
localhost
```

or

```ini
[prod:children]
k8s_cluster
localhost
```

but that is not allowed.

Comment: Instead of using "_but that is not allowed_" an error message is the more significant information and will help others to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look into [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) and [Grouping groups: parent/child group relationships](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#grouping-groups-parent-child-group-relationships)

> *You can create parent/child relationships among groups. Parent groups are also known as nested groups or groups of groups.*

This means you can't put a host into a child group without having em in a group before. Otherwise you would receive an error message like

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse k8s.ini with ini plugin:
k8s.ini:15: Section [prod:children] includes undefined group: localhost
```

An example inventory `k8s.ini`

```ini
[control_node]
localhost

[k8s_masters]
k8s-master01

[k8s_nodes]
k8s-node01
k8s-node02

[k8s_cluster:children]
k8s_masters
k8s_nodes

[prod:children]
control_node
k8s_cluster
```

called via

```bash
ansible-inventory -i k8s.ini --graph
```

will result into the requested output of

```yaml
@all:
  |--@prod:
  |  |--@control_node:
  |  |  |--localhost
  |  |--@k8s_cluster:
  |  |  |--@k8s_masters:
  |  |  |  |--k8s-master01
  |  |  |--@k8s_nodes:
  |  |  |  |--k8s-node01
  |  |  |  |--k8s-node02
  |--@ungrouped:
```

You may also have a look into the output of

```bash
ansible-inventory -i k8s.ini prod --graph
ansible-inventory -i k8s.ini control_node --graph
```

Furthermore I recommend to use the real hostname, in example `test.example.com` instead of `localhost` within the inventory and have also a look into the meaning of [Default groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#default-groups).

**Further Reading**

- [Implicit `localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html)
- [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

Comment: not sure why i did not think of add group to localhost. I expected localhsot to be some ansible default thing.

Comment: And that it is according [Implicit `localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html). However, you are trying to create group of groups which isn't possible with hosts as direct member. So your problem isn't related to localhost and would be the same for any hostname.